# Remove a file in Amazon S3 using Django-storages

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-storage

In my Django project I use Django-storageS to save media files in my Amazon S3.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) (I use also Django-rest-framework). This works well for me: I can upload some images and I can see these on my S3 storage.

But, if I try to remove an instance of my model (that contains an ImageField) this not removes the corresponding file in S3. Is correct this? I need t remove also the resource in S3.

Answer (score 8):

Deleting a record will not automatically delete the file in the S3 Bucket. In order to delete the S3 resource you need to call the following method on your file field:

```py
model.filefield.delete(save=False)  # delete file in S3 storage
```

You can perform this either in

1. The `delete` method of your model
2. A `pre_delete` signal

Here is an example of how you can achieve this in the `delete` model method:

```
def delete(self):
    self.filefield.delete(save=False)
    super().delete()
```

Comment: How would the code even know to delete it from S3? I have just tried it. It does not seem to work.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, you need to set this up in your Django settings file, according to the documentation https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html. This is how the code knows where your bucket and file is so that it can delete the file. The settings also provide the credentials so that Django has permissions to delete the file. You need to also make sure you grant the Django IAM user permission to delete the file in AWS. All of that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Note: Overriding the delete() method  for an object may may not work when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet. In such case using  [Django Signals](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) may be preferred.

Comment: Works briliantly. Docs to explain how and Why:
        https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete

Answer (score 3):

You can delete S3 files by offering its id (filename in the S3 storage) using following code:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
from django.conf import settings

def s3_delete(id):
    s3conn = boto.connect_s3(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    bucket = s3conn.get_bucket(settings.S3_BUCKET)

    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = str(id)
    k.delete()
```

Make sure that you setup S3 variable correctly in settings.py including: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `S3_BUCKET`.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in aws s3,hope it helps

```
import os


@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=YourModelName)
def auto_delete_file_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.image:
        instance.image.delete(save=False)  ## use for aws s3
        # if os.path.isfile(instance.image.path): ## use this in development
        #     os.remove(instance.image.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a function to Django admin panel since in my case I don't remove files frequently.
If you want to delete files using API you may write your own `destroy()` in your serializer.

```
BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
s3 = boto3.client('s3')


class UserFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('file')
    actions = ['delete_completely']

    def delete_completely(self, request, queryset):
        for filemodel in queryset:
            s3.delete_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=str(filemodel.file))
            filemodel.delete()

    delete_completely.short_description = 'Delete pointer and real file together'
```