# remove orphaned file from a model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, media

I have the following model:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60)

    video = models.FileField(
        upload_to = class_files_custom_upload, 
        validators = [
            FileExtensionValidator(['mp4', 'webm', 'mpg', 'mpeg', 'ogv']),
        ]
    )

    section =  models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'clase'
        verbose_name_plural = 'clases'
        ordering = ['created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I create an instance of this model, but if I update the `video` field with another file of any instance, the previous saved file is orphaned and the file takes up space and I want to avoid it, deleting the file.

To do this I customize the file load, putting a callable in the [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
def class_files_custom_upload(instance, filename):
    try:
        old_instance = Class.objects.get(id = instance.id)
        old_instance.video.delete()
    except Class.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return os.path.join('courses/videos', generate_secure_filename(filename))
```

In this way I achieve my goal. But I have several models that save multimedia files, and for each one I have to customize the file load, practically doing a function almost equal to `class_files_custom_upload`, and the code repeats and this is not optimal at all.

I tried to create a reusable function that meets the goal of the `class_files_custom_upload` function, in various fields like `ImageField` and `FileField`, but I can't do it since the function receives only 2 parameters, `instance` and `filename`, which is too little data to achieve it.

The only way I managed to create that "function" that meets the goal and is reusable, was to create a validator:

```py
def delete_orphaned_media_file(value):
    old_instance = value.instance.__class__.objects.get(pk = value.instance.pk)
    media_file_field = getattr(old_instance, value.field.name)

    if not media_file_field.name == value.name: media_file_field.delete()
```

And it works, but after all it is a "validator", a "validator" is supposed to validate a field, not "that". My question is, is it good practice to do this?

Is there a better alternative to my solution? but that this alternative meets the objective of being reusable.

Any suggestion helps my learning, thanks.

Comment: Well the problem is that strictly speaking, two or more fields can refer to the same file, so just removing the old one os not safe.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problem is that, two or more `FileField`s can refer to the same file. In the database a `FileField` stores the location of the file, so two or more columns can have the same file, therefore, just removing the old one is not (completely) safe.

You can for example make use of [**`django-unused-media`**](https://github.com/akolpakov/django-unused-media). You install this with:

```
$ pip install django-unused-media
```

Next you add this to the installed apps:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'django_unused_media',
    # …
]
```

Next you can run:

```
python3 manage.py cleanup_unused_media
```

this will look for files that are no longer referenced, and clean these up interactively.

You can also make a scheduled task (for example with `cron`), that runs with the `--no-input` flag:

```
python3 manage.py cleanup_unused_media --no-input
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that, but in an automated way?

Comment: @JulioCesar: the problem with automating this, is that it is not transaction-safe (like here https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup). Furthermore certain database updates *circumvent* the triggers, like bulk updates, etc. Finally if you manually update the database (or with another application), it will not work effectively either.

Comment: So is it better and safer to delete orphaned files manually, i.e with `django-unused-media`?

Comment: @JulioCesar: not manually, as said, you can set a scheduled task (for example a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)) for example that runs every day, or every certain hours.

Comment: This does not work if you use s3 for media storage

Comment: @Chymdy: yes, that is because Django does not automatically remove the file when `.remove()` is called: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29373983/67579

Comment: @Chymdy: I think updating it to also work for other storage endpoints might not be that hard. WIll take a look into it. Likely the most problematic part is limiting the number of requests to remove (a lot) of files.