# Django: How to delete Media Files on Digitalocean Spaces/ Amazon S3 automatically when Model instance is deleted

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-models, digital-ocean-spaces

I have the following model defined in my Django-App

```
def directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'attachments/{0}_{1}/{2}'.format(instance.date, instance.title, filename)

class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    # File will be saved to MEDIA_ROOT/attachments
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=directory_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I successfully set up AWS S3/ Digitalocean Spaces to store the media file uploaded via the attachment field. However, when I delete an instance of the model, the file remains in my bucket. What do I have to do, in order to delete the file automatically in my s3 bucket, if the corresponding model intance is deleted?

Comment: I think this might help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373983/remove-a-file-in-amazon-s3-using-django-storages/51685047](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373983/remove-a-file-in-amazon-s3-using-django-storages/51685047)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the easiest way seems to be using the third-party-package `django-cleanup`, see https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup for details.

The only thing you need to do is install the app, add it at the bottom of your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` and that's it.

When I delete a model instance, the file also gets automatically deleted in my Amazon S3/Digitalocean Spaces bucket.